# How to add multiple "message" event listeners for the same react component?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, addeventlistener

I have a Rich Edit component that loads as an iframe. This component is used in two places and the problem is that two listeners work at the same time. How to separate two listeners from each other?
I use this hook

```
const useMessage = (callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("message", callback);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("message", callback);
  }, [callback]);
};
```

Then I call it in the component, I pass the handler through the props.

```
useMessage(handler);
```

This is how I create an iframe, passing ID through props.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const iframe = document.getElementById(frameId);
    window.onmessage = function (event) {
      const origin = "*";
      let customMessage =
        event.data.type && event.data.type.indexOf("webpack") === -1;
      if (customMessage) {
        switch (event.data.type) {
          case "error":
            toast.error(event.data.response);
            break;
          case "sendText":
            break;
          case "sendLoadText":
            break;
          default:
            console.log(event);
            toast.warn("Unknown answer: " + event.data.type);
        }
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: you can specify a target origin that is used to filter the messages received by the window.onmessage event listener and then compare the event data (event.origin) with the specified target origin to compare if the particular instance is the intended recipient. 


Then in your use effect, you can specify the origin via ` const origin = event.origin;` and then modify you ` if (customMessage) {}` to also include a check if the event origin is the intended targetOrigin.

Comment: If it's not difficult for you, please write an example of how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/T7SDjqWm something like this. I didnt add this as an answer because I think is my opinion on how it could be done. If it does work for you, let me know and add an answer to the question on how u solved it to help others.

Comment: The fact is that these listeners have one iframe, that is, the same origin.